# GTK3 C program linked with MuPDF fails (even if not called)

Tags: c, gtk3, mupdf

For context, I am not new to programming but am new to unix and GTK, so this may be something simple but I am in head banging mode.

I have built MuPDF from source successfully including standalone examples that run.

I have just started to learn GTK3 calling from C and had the simplest example working, when I decided to try to combine the two. Long story short - after pruning it down, I find I am getting a segmentation fault at run time when certain lines of code related to MuPDF are compiled and linked, even if not called. The code should be short enough to follow, I hope:

main.c

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include "MuPDF_calls.h"

static void activate (GtkApplication *app, gpointer user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *button;
  GtkWidget *button_box;

  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 200, 200);

  button_box = gtk_button_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), button_box);
  button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Hello World");
  g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (gtk_widget_destroy), window);
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (button_box), button);

  gtk_widget_show_all (window);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;
  app = gtk_application_new ("com.leferguson.musicalpi", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}
```

Note with the exception of the header this is almost literally from the GTK+ tutorials, and does nothing but put up a window and button.  It does not actually call the routine which follows next:

Header file for completness: MuPDF_calls.h

```
#ifndef MUPDF_CALLS_H_
#define MUPDF_CALLS_H_

extern int getApage();

#endif /* MUPDF_CALLS_H_ */
```

And the MuPDF_calls.c

```
#include <mupdf/fitz.h>

extern int getApage()
{
    // Notice that this routine is not actually called by the main program

        fz_context *ctx;

        /* Create a context to hold the exception stack and various caches. */
        ctx = fz_new_context(NULL, NULL, FZ_STORE_UNLIMITED);
        if (!ctx)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "cannot create mupdf context\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
// If the section below this up to the closing brace before the last return is removed, the program works
// With this included, it gets a terminated, exit value -1, segmentation fault in do_scavenging_malloc()
        fz_try(ctx)
            fz_register_document_handlers(ctx);
        fz_catch(ctx)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "cannot register document handlers: %s\n", fz_caught_message(ctx));
            fz_drop_context(ctx);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This routine is basically the first section of example.c from the MuPDF sources, with most of the code removed for brevity here to leave in enough to show the failure.

And finally these are built with the following commands:

```
gcc -g `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -c main.c -o build/main.o 
gcc -g -I/home/ferguson/git/mupdf/include -c MuPDF_calls.c -o build/MuPDF_calls.o 
gcc -g build/main.o `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`  build/MuPDF_calls.o   -L/home/ferguson/git/mupdf/build/release -lmupdf -lmupdfthird  -lm -lc -lgcc -lssl -lcrypto -o build/TestGTK
```

Obviously if you try to recreate this adjust the paths as appropriate. I do not suggest this is pretty or complete, it is a stripped version try to get the minimum necessary to fail.

Again, please note that the ugly-named getApage routine is not actually called in main(). But if I build this (and link it in) with the last try/catch section included in the source, the program gives a segmentation fault at runtime somewhere in the GTK routines (no window is displayed).

If I comment out the indicated lines and make no other changes, and run, it puts up a window as expected.  If I run it in debug with breaks set in the code I do not intend to call it does not reach it (as it should not).

I separated the programs and compile with different include paths just to make sure there were no unrelated defines that might conflict, it makes no difference.

I have expanded the macros in the relevant code and nothing jumps out at me (and it is syntactically correct, and if I compile with the expanded code instead of the macros, it behaves identically. There are no related compiler warnings.

This is happening on Ubuntu 16.04, updated current for it and all the related build items.  It's in a big VM with lots of memory (8G) and nothing else running.  It is 100% reproducible. The error takes about 2 seconds to occur, which is about how long it would normally take for the window to appear.

I just don't know how to fix a bug in a program that is not being called. :(

More seriously, I expect this is causing some kind of naming conflict in routines or modules loaded, or sequence they are searched, or some incompatibilities in just using these together, but experimentation has gotten me nowhere, and I do not know where to start looking.

Any advice?

> > > added 10/27/16 ldd output.  I did an ldd on a running version (code commented) and not running, and they are the same modules, identially (different addresses of course). I wasn't aware MuPDF used GTK.  I looked through its source tree and see it referenced in a few examples (which now that I see them I need to go look more closely at), but I do not see it in the primary viewer, though maybe it appears in a form I would not recognize?

However, I suspect this is the right track, and that including the MuPDF code is somehow dragging in some module incompatible with the GTK3 setup.  I just don't know how to find it (especially seeing the ldd output is the same).

```
ldd TestGTK
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc5bfef000)
        libgtk-3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0 (0x00007f2310ad5000)
        libgio-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f231074d000)
        libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f23104f9000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f23101f0000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f230fe27000)
        libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f230f9e2000)
        libgdk-3.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk-3.so.0 (0x00007f230f707000)
        libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f230f503000)
        libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f230f2f5000)
        libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f230efbb000)
        libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007f230edab000)
        libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f230eba4000)
        libcairo-gobject.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo-gobject.so.2 (0x00007f230e99b000)
        libcairo.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2 (0x00007f230e687000)
        libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f230e464000)
        libatk-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f230e23f000)
        libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f230e010000)
        libepoxy.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libepoxy.so.0 (0x00007f230dd1a000)
        libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f230db04000)
        libpango-1.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0x00007f230d8b8000)
        libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007f230d674000)
        libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007f230d363000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f230d146000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f230cf2b000)
        libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f230cd09000)
        libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f230caed000)
        libffi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6 (0x00007f230c8e5000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000556c9118f000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f230c6e1000)
        libXinerama.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1 (0x00007f230c4dd000)
        libXrandr.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2 (0x00007f230c2d2000)
        libXcursor.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1 (0x00007f230c0c8000)
        libXcomposite.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcomposite.so.1 (0x00007f230bec4000)
        libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007f230bcc1000)
        libxkbcommon.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxkbcommon.so.0 (0x00007f230ba82000)
        libwayland-cursor.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-cursor.so.0 (0x00007f230b879000)
        libwayland-egl.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-egl.so.1 (0x00007f230b677000)
        libwayland-client.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwayland-client.so.0 (0x00007f230b469000)
        libmirclient.so.9 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirclient.so.9 (0x00007f230b1e7000)
        libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f230afd5000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f230adcd000)
        libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007f230ab22000)
        libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f230a900000)
        libpixman-1.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0 (0x00007f230a657000)
        libpng12.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (0x00007f230a432000)
        libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007f230a22e000)
        libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007f230a023000)
        libXrender.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1 (0x00007f2309e19000)
        libatspi.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatspi.so.0 (0x00007f2309be9000)
        libdbus-1.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007f230999d000)
        libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007f230973f000)
        libthai.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthai.so.0 (0x00007f2309535000)
        libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f230930c000)
        libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f230909b000)
        libmircommon.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmircommon.so.5 (0x00007f2308e6a000)
        libmirprotobuf.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirprotobuf.so.3 (0x00007f2308c08000)
        libboost_system.so.1.58.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.58.0 (0x00007f2308a04000)
        libprotobuf-lite.so.9 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf-lite.so.9 (0x00007f23087d3000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f2308450000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f230823a000)
        libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f2308035000)
        libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f2307e2f000)
        libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007f2307da9000)
        libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007f2307b84000)
        libdatrie.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdatrie.so.1 (0x00007f230797c000)
        libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so.1.58.0 (0x00007f2307763000)
        liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f2307541000)
        libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007f230725f000)
        libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007f230704b000)
```

Incidentally, this is the code with macros expanded that if removed allows it to run, and if left in causes the failure (even though the code is never encountered).  Of interest, __sigsetjmp is in different headers in the include libraries of MuPDF and the GTK3 example, but I can't see it is changing what is linked, but I'm suspicious this is related.

```
            ctx = fz_new_context(NULL, NULL, FZ_STORE_UNLIMITED);
            if (!ctx)
            {
                    fprintf(stderr, "cannot create mupdf context\n");
                    return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }


            { if (fz_push_try(ctx))
                    { if (__sigsetjmp ( (ctx)->error->top->buffer,0) == 0)
                            do
                                    fz_register_document_handlers(ctx);
                            while (0);
                    }
            }
            if ((ctx->error->top--)->code > 1)
            {
                    fprintf(stderr , "cannot register document handlers: %s\n", fz_caught_message(ctx));
                    fz_drop_context(ctx);
                    return 1;
            }
```

> > > Update #2 on 10/27/2016: I may be fooling myself but think I am getting closer. The failure is coming in hb_calloc, which is part of harfbuzz, which is actually included in the MuPDF distribution.  It looks like GTK ends up calling something called pango_shape_full which later calls hb_ft_face_create and through a few more calls hb_calloc where an assertion fails.  But it is getting those routines from inside of the source included with MuPDF, which clearly does not happen when MuPDF is not involved (why, or even if, it relates to the specific lines of code I do not know).

I've found out how to create a link map but not how to interpret it.  For example, hb_calloc appears to be in crtl, which is also loaded, but then it appears again later (further in the listing at least) as coming from the libmupdf.a library built from sources.  My GUESS is this cross-over is at issue in some fashion, though I have yet to see why, or how to maintain control or separation of this.  I have rearranged the order of libs in linking and cannot find any combination that makes a difference.

There are also negative comments about this on MuPDF (e.g. [here](https://github.com/muennich/mupdf/blob/master/source/fitz/harfbuzz.c)) but I am not nearly deep enough in what is happening to tell if it is relevant.  But I do have a feeling that the code in MuPDF relating to harfbuz is conflicting with what normally runs with GTK3, that I have somehow replaced canned harfbuz functions that worked with GTK, with some that do not. I'm going to try removing that c source in MuPDF and rebuild but my guess is I'll trade breaking GTK with breaking MuPDF, it may just take a lot longer to find out as I'm further from using it for real.

Or am I on the wrong path?

Comment: Maybe MuPDF is linked to other version of GTK than your app (like GTK2 instead of GTK3). Try running `ldd build/TestGTK`.

Comment: I think I am giving up on this. I tried using the distro version of MuPDF, but it links against libopenjpeg, and apparently there are know problems with that (undefined link time references) which require rebuilding MuPDF, bringing me back full circle. I did a QT5 project which yielded the same results (but thinking that if it built the make file it might be smarter). I tried a .so and dynamic load of the MuPDF stuff to isolate the conflicting functions but that requires building MuPDF as PIC and I doubt I would succeed in pulling that thread to the end. Still hoping for a magic solution?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that GTK calls some functions from the system harfbuzz shared library, but it gets confused and calls the harfbuzz version stored in libmupdfthird.a library instead (it can be seen using valgrind).

To fix it I've done the following:

Let's say you have the file `module.o` that needs to be linked to MuPDF, you can link them with `ld -L<directory_to_search_mupdf_libraries> -r -o newmodule.o module.o -lmupdf -lmupdfthird`

Now you have a `newmodule.o` file with all its dependencies bounded, but if you link it with GTK you will have the previous name collision. To fix it you have to make all the harfbuzz symbols from `newmodule.o` local to that file, this way in the linking process there will be no possible confusion. You can do this with `objcopy -w -L hb_* newmodule.o` which makes local all symbols starting with "hb_".

Now you can do something like `` gcc main.o newmodule.o -o main `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` `` and it should work.

Comment: I no longer even have an environment where I can test this, but your comments seem reasonable and I appreciate the answer, and will mark it such with the caveat I am unable to test.